# How do I split and and remove white space from this latitude and longitude object?

Tags: javascript

The coordinates are random numbers for privacy. This is an example of the object:

```
{
  '0': '2',
  '1': '5',
  '2': '.',
  '3': '1',
  '4': '3',
  '5': '4',
  '6': '2',
  '7': '0',
  '8': '0',
  '9': ',',
  '10': ' ',
  '11': '-',
  '12': '3',
  '13': '8',
  '14': '.',
  '15': '5',
  '16': '4',
  '17': '9',
  '18': '2',
  '19': '0',
  '20': '2'
}
```

How do I split the values by a comma and put them into their own constants?

Comment: Any feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values` to get an array, then join it, and split it by comma. Finally convert the split parts to number:

```js
const data = {'0': '2','1': '5','2': '.','3': '1','4': '3','5': '4','6': '2','7': '0','8': '0','9': ',','10': ' ','11': '-','12': '3','13': '8','14': '.','15': '5','16': '4','17': '9','18': '2','19': '0','20': '2'};

const [long, lat] = Object.values(data).join("").split(",").map(Number);
console.log(long, lat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the following, but Trincot's answer is much better.

```js
const data = {'0': '2','1': '5','2': '.','3': '1','4': '3','5': '4','6': '2','7': '0','8': '0','9': ',','10': ' ','11': '-','12': '3','13': '8','14': '.','15': '5','16': '4','17': '9','18': '2','19': '0','20': '2'};


const convertArrayItemsToInt = (digist_array) => {
  return parseFloat(
    digist_array.reduce((complete_number, currentDigit) => {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(currentDigit)) || currentDigit == ".") {
        complete_number += currentDigit;
      }
      return complete_number;
    }, "")
  );
};

//Get only the values
const coordinates = Object.values(data);
//Get the comma index
const comma_index = coordinates.indexOf(",");
//Split the array by the comma and give it to convertArrayItemsToInt
const lat = convertArrayItemsToInt(coordinates.slice(0, comma_index));
const lng = convertArrayItemsToInt(
  coordinates.slice(comma_index, coordinates.length)
);
```